# Pyspark - create a new column using startswith from list

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

What is the best possible way to add a new column based on string checking condition

have to create a new column using existing column value if it startswith some defined values:

```
|deliveryname|department|state|salary|
+-------------+----------+-----+------+
|          LA|     Sales|   NY| 90000|
|      Austin|     Sales|   NY| 86000|
|      Robert|     Sales|   CA| 81000|
|     Snooze |   Finance|   CA| 90000|
|     MidWest|   Finance|   NY| 83000|
|        Jeff| Marketing|   CA| 80000|

df= df.withColumn("DeliveryPossible",when(df.deliveryname.startswith(s) for s in (('LO - ','Austin','MidWest','San Antonios', 'Snooze ea')),'True').otherwise('False'))
```

or

```
values = ['LO - ','Austin','MidWest','San Antonios', 'Snooze ea']

df.withColumn("DeliveryPossible",when(df.company_name.startswith(s) for s in values ,'True').otherwise('False')).show()
```

Required OUTPUT:

```
|deliveryname|department|state|salary|DeliveryPossible
+-------------+----------+-----+------+
|          LA|     Sales|   NY| 90000|False
|      Austin|     Sales|   NY| 86000|True
|      Robert|     Sales|   CA| 81000|False
|     Snooze |   Finance|   CA| 90000|True
|     MidWest|   Finance|   NY| 83000|True
|        Jeff| Marketing|   CA| 80000|False
```

And I'm getting same error in both, I figured I'm missing parenthesis but not able to figure out where to put. And also is this correct way of doing this?

> Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df.startswith()` only accepts one string as its argument. You need to set up the conditions separately and combine them using 'OR'.

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

values = ['LO - ','Austin','MidWest','San Antonios', 'Snooze ea']

df.withColumn("DeliveryPossible",
              reduce(or_, [df.company_name.startswith(s) for s in values])
             ).show()
```